# Should we remove the annoyances tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The tag [annoyances](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/annoyances) doesn't seem to serve any constructive purpose. It can only be used on questions that are complaints in nature. Whether the situation described in the question is annoying is entirely subjective. With sufficient pessimism, this tag can be applied to *any* question.

Thankfully, this tag isn't currently popular, as it is used by just 4 questions (of which one is closed and one is a duplicate). Should we just get rid of this tag?

Comment: You're saying that [tag:annoyances] is annoying?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yes, pretty much. Without any doubt, it is the most annoying tag we have here. :-)

Comment: Agreed.  In light of our play nice policy, an "annoyances" tag isn't nice.

Comment: I'm getting annoyed just thinking about that tag! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tL9JgMt4okM

Comment: why would you want to get rid of a day?  Ach, sorry, English!

Answer (score 6):

> Should we just get rid of this tag?

Yes we should get rid of it.  This TAG does not conform to our play nice policy.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see anything fundamentally wrong with a tag to indicate that a question is asking how to deal with situations in the workplace involving coworkers (or other things) the asker finds annoying.

It can be considered similar (but not synonymous) to [distractions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distractions).

I wouldn't say it should apply to annoying **situations** (as in it's annoying that [I don't have documentation of this work I did](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/95590/should-i-list-undocumented-work-cash-on-an-employment-verification-and-or-resu)), but rather annoying **things** (as in this person is annoying). Of course how annoying something is is entirely subjective, but that's irrelevant - the fact that the asker finds it annoying is sufficient to justify the question about it.

This seems like a good (or not terrible) use of the tag: [How to handle a coworker's breath odor?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/63917/how-to-handle-a-coworkers-breath-odor)

This seems like a bad use of the tag: [Too many Charitable causes in the workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/42701/too-many-charitable-causes-in-the-workplace)

This is perhaps somewhat of a borderline case, tending towards getting rid of the tag (since it's more about the situation of the coworker continuing the explanation being annoying than the coworker itself being annoying, although that's a confusing line): [How to politely tell someone to stop explaining?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/65956/how-to-politely-tell-someone-to-stop-explaining)

---

**Conclusion:** Seems like a valid tag **in theory**. While it currently has a sum total of 0 appropriate uses on open questions, I don't see a pressing need to get rid of it - we may as well leave it around for future questions or find a few appropriate questions to apply it to.